# Connection ZKteco with my c# Application?

Tags: c#, tcp, rfid, zkteco

i have been using the ZKFinger SDk but that doesn't provide enough info.

5.3.4

```
`OpenDevice
[Function]
public static IntPtr OpenDevice(int index)
[Purpose]
This function is used to connect to a device.
[Parameter Description]
7
Index:
Device index (The values ranges from 0 to n and n indicates the device count minus 
1.)
[Return Value]
Device Handle`
```

This is the function explanation in SDK pdf file and i am uanble to find how my devie will communicate with my program?? how will this function get my ip address etc??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have installed my software at location "A", my device at location "B" and database at location "C", my device and software is connected on the same network vis tcp/ip, my software receives data from my device and stores it to my db. if my software is shutdown for some reason, my device will let them scan and open the door can you explain how will i be able to store the check in or check out info of that user when the system is turned on? cant find anything in the SDK

Comment: @ABJ4727 you're doing it wrong. The fingerprint device is just a sensor or a reader. It does not track check-ins & check-outs, not does it open nor close the door. You need to connect to the main controller. See this: https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper/